# Create a tree structure of Keras layers in python

Tags: keras

I'm trying to obtain a structure of Keras layer. Within a simple network, this is possible by just iterating through the `model.layers`. However, if the network is complex (e.g. concatenates different layer) this approach is not sufficient.
This is an example:

```
FEATURES = ['A','B','C','D']
IMPORTANT_FEATURES = [0, 3]
NORMAL_FEATURES = [1, 2]
inputLayer = [Input(shape=(1, )) for i,f in enumerate(FEATURES)]
importantInput = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([inputLayer[i] for i in IMPORTANT_FEATURES])
layer1 = Dense()(importantInput)
normalInput  = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)(layer1 + [inputLayer[i] for i in NORMAL_FEATURES])
layer2 = Dense()(normalInput)
model = Model([
    inputLayer[i]
    for i in range(len(FEATURES))
], layer2)
```

This produces in `model.layer` a list of **Keras** layers composed like this:

```
[Input1, Input2, Concatenate1, Dense1, Input3, Input4, Concatenate2, Dense2]
```

The only way to get which level is in input to the concatenate is to access to `Concatenate1.input`. However, this returns a list of **Tensorflow** layers.
Is it possible to obtain a tree-structure of layers just using **Keras** layers?

Answer (score 0):

The **Keras** list of input layers can be obtained by `Concatenate1._inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers`

Comment: Is this supposed to be an *answer*, or an edit to your original question?

Comment: this is the answer